# Ionic 5 (Angular) can't set <ion-datetime> time

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to dynamically set the value of this `ion-datetime` component:

```
<ion-datetime 
  displayFormat="HH:mm:ss" 
  [(ngModel)]="rest"
></ion-datetime>
```

This is the Typescript relevant code:

```
export class AddFreefromComponent implements OnInit {
  rest: string = "2000-01-01T00:02:04-06:00";
```

As you can notice, I straight added a valid ISO string to test it, but [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxQuL.png).

Funny enough, if I hardcode the same string, [I get what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PAiE.png):

```
<ion-datetime
  displayFormat="HH:mm:ss"
  value="2000-01-01T00:02:04-06:00"
></ion-datetime>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using `ngModel` I surely get the value when it's changed by the user, but it somehow doesn't work to initially set the `ion-datetime`.
In fact, I got the ISO string I'm using to do this test from `[(ngModel)]="rest"`.

Comment: Can you see any error on the console? Are you importing FormsModule in order to use ngModel?

Comment: Yep. No errors, FormsModule imported.

Further tests show me the date gets actually set, but not the hour. Do you think I should fill an issue to Ionic?

Comment: I don't have any problem using your code, you can check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-9-start-template-nayelg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.page.html

Comment: Ugh. I see.I'll try to reinstall Ionic or something.

Comment: Check the dependencies, I'm using ionic/angular@5.0.0 on Stackblitz and angular@9.

Comment: This must be a sick joke. I tried to update and now I get `'IteratorResult' was also declared here.`. Tried everything I could to fix that but nothing works. Oh well... I'll tell you if I manage to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you get to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For who that still in doubt, there is a simple way to do this.

On .html file:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm:ss" 
pickerFormat="HH:mm:ss" [(ngModel)]="rest" 
placeholder="{{ rest | date:'HH:mm:ss' }}"
(ionChange)="getValue($event.target.value)">
</ion-datetime>
```

On .ts file:

```
rest: string = "2021-05-01T18:59:12.732-03:00";
```

Also dynamically set the value like this:

```
rest = Date();
```

And to get the value:

```
getValue(value){
    console.log('Date Result: ', value);
}
```